# <Ctrl>-<Tab> switch between tabs in current application

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, 18.04

I've recently installed Kubuntu 18.04.

I've found that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't switch between tabs in the current application.

I've gone to `System Settings` -> `Shortcuts` -> `Global Shortcuts` -> `KWin`

- For `"Walk Through Window Tabs"` I've specified shortcut `Ctrl+Tab`
- For `"Walk Through Window Tabs (Reverse)"` I've specified shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+Tab`

This doesn't seem to work.

How can I enable this behaviour?

Comment: Chrome - I'll try reboot

Comment: Whaaaaat? Thank you! I deleted them and now it works... not sure what happened, as I only added them in the first place because it wasn't working before!

Comment: Before I read your question, I hadn't set those shortcuts at all and Ctrl+Tab worked, as I said. Then, just to check I set it in Global Shortcuts and then I couldn't change tabs. Removing them and all is well again. Something to ponder!

Comment: Perhaps a bug in kde?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. Removing the global shortcut for tabbing through open windows of an application has fixed my tabbing through Firefox. Still doesn't work for gedit, but that's a fight for another day.